# angular.js - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined

Tags: angularjs

I created an angular app with yeoman via the [angular-fullstack generator](https://github.com/DaftMonk/generator-angular-fullstack).

Now I'm trying to run the client part of the app on an android device via phonegap.

I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined      angular.js:4407
```

This is the part of the angular.js file that produces this error:

```
////////////////////////////////////
// internal Injector
////////////////////////////////////

function createInternalInjector(cache, factory) {

  function getService(serviceName, caller) {
    if (cache.hasOwnProperty(serviceName)) {
      if (cache[serviceName] === INSTANTIATING) {
        throw $injectorMinErr('cdep', 'Circular dependency found: {0}',
                  serviceName + ' <- ' + path.join(' <- '));
      }
      return cache[serviceName];
    } else {
      try {
        path.unshift(serviceName);
        cache[serviceName] = INSTANTIATING;
        return cache[serviceName] = factory(serviceName, caller);
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        if (cache[serviceName] === INSTANTIATING) {
          delete cache[serviceName];
        }
        throw err;
      } finally {
        path.shift();
      }
    }
  }
  ...
```

I have a hard time debugging this since the error occurs only on the android device. In the browser it works fine.

Comment: it isn't angular failing here, it is whatever your code is asking angular to process.  It is impossible for us to know what that is with the code you provided here.  However, if this only occurs on mobile devices, it is probably some function using a phonegap feature.

Comment: any idea how to trace back this error in this situation?

Comment: well, this function is the Injection function, so if it happens when your app first starts or first loads a page, you probably should look at what services are being injected into that page.  specifically, look at something in your code that is running a `.replace` call, because this isn't angular.

Comment: in fact, which version of Angular is this? I don't even see this code in the current angular source, which is most certainly nowhere near 4407 lines long....

Comment: It is version 1.4.1.
I logged 'serviceName' and 'caller', its $rootElement and $location. I removed all dependencies except for ui-router and get the same error. I'm really lost in this.